# Powershell - manage txt file content

Tags: powershell

My task is to find in a TXT file line with a specific work, like `<marker>`. If the script will find the line with word `<marker>` - for example it will be `line[20]`. Next I need to copy `line [19]`, `line[20]` and `line[21]`, then paste it accordingly: content of `line [19]` to `line[21]`, content of `line [20]` to `line[22]`, content of `line [21]` to `line[23]`. the main loop should be executed specific number of times - `$counter`. My code below, it does not work as expected.

```
$filename = "filename.yaml"
$content = Get-Content -Path .\$filename

$counter = 1
while ($counter -gt 0 ) {
    for ($i=0; $i -le ($content.Count); $i++) {
        if ($content[$i] -like "*<marker>*" ) {
        
            Add-Content -Path .\$filename ""

            $content[$i+2] = $content[$i-1]
            $content[$i+3] = $content[$i]
            $content[$i+4] = $content[$i+1]
            $content | Set-Content .\$filename

            $counter--

        }
    }
}
```

Input file sample:

```
List:
    - A: "value1"
      B: "<marker>"
      C: "<value2>"
```

Required output file, when `$counter=2` :

```
List:
    - A: "value1"
      B: "<marker>"
      C: "<value2>"
    - A: "value1"
      B: "<marker>"
      C: "<value2>"
    - A: "value1"
      B: "<marker>"
      C: "<value2>"
```

Comment: If the file is [Yaml](https://yaml.org/), consider using yaml library that understands how the data structures are parsed properly.

Comment: yes I know that module, but in my case cant use it, so I have to use rather standard powershell modules.

Comment: Please add a sample input file and what you expect (and actually) get.

Comment: I have updated post, wit input file sample and required output file structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below powershell script. We can leverage select-string, which brings context of a match.

```bsh
$cnt = 2 #number of times to paste
$ContextFile = "c:\dev\Context.txt"
$content = Get-Content -Path C:\dev\test.txt | select-string -Pattern "<marker>" -Context 1,1 
for($num= 0; $num -lt $cnt ; $num++){
  $filecontent += $content.ToString()
}
Set-Content -Path "C:\dev\MatchResult.txt"  -Value $filecontent
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, but it does not work as expected :( It removes all the content from the file, and `$content` variable contains additional character ">". Apart from mentioned your code produces too many lines in the output file. but I like the idea of this line --> "$content = Get-Content -Path .\$ContextFile | select-string -Pattern "<cond_key>" -Context 1,1"

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case it would be easiest to use a Generic [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) object so we can make use of its `InsertRange()` method like this:

```
$content = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\filename.yaml'
# use a List object of type String so we can make use of its InsertRange() method
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new([string[]]$content)

$repeatCounter = 2
$i = 0
while ($i -lt $list.Count) {
    if ($list[$i] -like "*<marker>*") {
        $copyLines = [string[]]$list[($i - 1)..($i + 1)]
        for ($count = 0; $count -lt $repeatCounter; $count++) {
            $list.InsertRange($i + 2, $copyLines)
            $i += 3
        }
    }
    $i++
}

$list | Set-Content -Path 'D:\Test\filename_update.yaml' -PassThru
```

Output using your sample:

```
List:
    - A: "value1"
      B: "<marker>"
      C: "<value2>"
    - A: "value1"
      B: "<marker>"
      C: "<value2>"
    - A: "value1"
      B: "<marker>"
      C: "<value2>"
```